# why can't i do the hashmap.put()

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Whenever i try to run my error is this "hmap.put(id, b0);" am i doing it correctly? im trying to do a user input and insert it in a hashmap.
it says:
no suitable method found for put(Integer,Student)
    method Map.put(Integer,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Student cannot be converted to String)
    method AbstractMap.put(Integer,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Student cannot be converted to String)
    method HashMap.put(Integer,String) is not applicable

### (argument mismatch; Student cannot be converted to String)

```j
package javaapplication30;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Student {
  int id;
  String sn, cor;

  public Student(int id, String sn, String cor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sn = sn;
    this.cor = cor;

  }
}

public class JavaApplication30 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap < Integer, String > hmap = new HashMap < Integer, String > ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      System.out.print("id: ");
      Integer id = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("name: ");
      String sn = sc.next();
      System.out.print("course: ");
      String cor = sc.next();

      Student b0 = new Student(id, sn, cor);

      hmap.put(id, b0);

    }

    for (Map.Entry m: hmap.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: type of `b0` is `Student` but should be  `String` or use  `HashMap < Integer, Student >`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thank you sooo much! i forgot about that one part and now i can fix it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the map to be a `HashMap<Integer, String>`.  In other words, the key type is `Integer` and the value type is `String`.

But then you do this:

```
  Student b0 = new Student(id, sn, cor);
  hmap.put(id, b0);
```

That is attempting to add a map entry where the value is a `Student`.

`Student` is not a subclass of `String` so that is not legal.

---

Here is what the error message says, and how to interpret it:

```
no suitable method found for put(Integer,Student)
```

That corresponds to this call `put(id, b0)`.  Observe that `id` is declared to be an `Integer` and `b0` is a `Student`

```
method Map.put(Integer,String) is not applicable
```

The compiler has found a `put` method in the `Map` interface whose signature is `put(Integer,String)`.  It has the correct *name* and the correct *number* of parameters. But ...

```
(argument mismatch; Student cannot be converted to String)
```

The compiler has tried to find a legal way to use that `put` method.  The first argument is compatible, but there is no conversion that will convert a `Student` (which is what the argument is) to a `String` (which is what the method requires).

The solution is to change the declaration of `hmap`:

```
HashMap<Integer, Student> hmap = new HashMap<>();
```

(The `<>` tells the compiler to infer (i.e. work out) the generic type parameters from the context.)

Answer (score 0):

You declared your Hasmap as :
`new HashMap<Integer, String>();`

Then your HashMap expects Integer as key and String as value.
Your object b0 is not a String, it's a Student object.

Then you should change your HashMap as `new HashMap<Integer, Student>();` ( or you can call toString() function on b0, it depends on what do you want to do)